# Extra padding/margin added to DatePicker on Android 7.1.1

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a custom dialog displaying the DatePicker, but the element adds an extra margin/padding to the right of the view. This happens only on Android 7.1.1, Nexus 6P, but works perfectly fine on other lower resolution phones. How do I remove the extra padding?
My XML layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:endYear="2012"
        android:startYear="1930" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this on Android 7.1.1:
[image: Problem Screenshot]

Edit: Added my Java code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_attributes);

    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Register");

    final TextView birthDateSelectedTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_birth_date);
    Button dialogOpenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_dialog_date_picker);
    dialogOpenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(UserAttributesActivity.this);
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserAttributesActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_date_picker, null);
            builder.setView(dialogView);
            final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                    month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
                    year = datePicker.getYear();
                    String date = "" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                    birthDateSelectedTextView.setText(date);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Post your java code if possible

Comment: @AnkitaShah Added it. I don't think I've done anything wrong on the Java side of it, because it works on all emulators I've setup to test my app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add Style with `AlertDialog.Builder` like as follow.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserAttributesActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar);
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ankita is right, but if you are using AppCompat things are a bit more involved:

Define a new style and extend AppCompat's `Light.Dialog` style

```
<style name="DatePickerDialogStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    ...
</style>
```

Then add attributes to mimic the `NoActionBar` part:

```
<style name="DatePickerDialogStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Lastly, now that you are no longer getting app compat colors from your `AppTheme`, copy them over to your new theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

<style name="DatePickerDialogStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary<item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_darkitem>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Then apply this new theme:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder 
    = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserAttributesActivity.this,
    DatePickerDialogStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
DatePickerDialog.Builder builder = null;
// 5.0+ 需要更换主题以去除右侧白边
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    builder = new DatePickerDialog.Builder(this.getActivity(),
            android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar);
}
// 4.4 不需要，相反加上会有白边
else {
    builder = new DatePickerDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a class like androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment(). Do this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Set the dialog style.
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar)
}
```