# Custom DatePicker and TimePicker in Preferences do not match those in Activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I am implementing a custom `TimePicker` for setting a preference in a `PreferenceFragmentCompat` fragment, following mainly [this](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-3-ae9793fd31ec) guide. While I have successfully made it work, the size of the Dialogs does not coincide with those of the same Dialog set in another Activity.

In the case of the `TimePicker` the one in the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` looks like this

[image: TimePicker in PreferenceFragmentCompat]

While if I put a `TimePicker` in any other Activity the looks is

[image: TimePicker in Activity]

For the case of `DatePicker`, the result in the Fragment looks like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456444/extra-padding-margin-added-to-datepicker-on-android-7-1-1), and the solution proposed there does not work in my case.

Is there a way of having the Pickers in the `PreferenceFragment` look like those in Activities? My implementation is the following:

`styles.xml`

```xml
<style name="Preference.App.DialogPreference" parent="Preference.Material">
    <item name="positiveButtonText">@android:string/ok</item>
    <item name="negativeButtonText">@android:string/cancel</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTitle" />
</style>
```

`SettingsActivity.kt`

```kotlin
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
        }
    
    
        override fun onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference: Preference) {
            // Try if the preference is one of our custom Preferences
            val dialogFragment: DialogFragment? = when (preference) {
                is TimePickerPreference -> {
                    // Create a new instance of TimePreferenceDialogFragment with the key of the related
                    // Preference
                    TimePickerPreferenceDialog.newInstance(preference.getKey())
                }
                else -> null
            }

            if (dialogFragment != null) {
                // The dialog was created (it was one of our custom Preferences), show the dialog for it
                dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0)
                dialogFragment.show(
                    parentFragmentManager,
                    "androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.DIALOG"
                )
            } else {
                // Dialog creation could not be handled here. Try with the super method.
                super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`TimePickerPreference.kt`

```kotlin
class TimePickerPreference @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context?,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.preferenceStyle,
    defStyleRes: Int = defStyleAttr
) : DialogPreference(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {

    companion object {
        private const val DEFAULT_VALUE = 0
    }

    var time: Int = DEFAULT_VALUE
        set(value) {
            field = value
            // Save to SharedPreferences
            persistInt(value)
        }

    override fun onGetDefaultValue(a: TypedArray?, index: Int): Any? {
        // Default value from attribute. Fallback value is set to 0.
        return a?.getInt(index, DEFAULT_VALUE) ?: DEFAULT_VALUE
    }

    override fun onSetInitialValue(defaultValue: Any?) {
        // Read the value. Use the default value if it is not possible.
        time = getPersistedInt((defaultValue as? Int) ?: DEFAULT_VALUE)
        val hour = time / 60
        val minute = time % 60
        summary = "$hour:${if (minute < 10) "0$minute" else "$minute"}"
    }
}
```

`TimePickerPreferenceDialog.kt`

```kotlin
class TimePickerPreferenceDialog : PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat() {

    private lateinit var timePicker: TimePicker

    override fun onCreateDialogView(context: Context?): View {
        timePicker = TimePicker(context)
        return timePicker
    }

    override fun onBindDialogView(view: View?) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view)

        // Get the time from the related Preference
        val minutesAfterMidnight: Int = preference.time

        // Set the time to the TimePicker
        val hours = minutesAfterMidnight / 60
        val minutes = minutesAfterMidnight % 60
        val is24hour = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)

        timePicker.apply {
            setIs24HourView(is24hour)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                hour = hours
                minute = minutes
            } else {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                currentHour = hours
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                currentMinute = minutes
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDialogClosed(positiveResult: Boolean) {
        if (positiveResult) {
            val hours: Int
            val minutes: Int
            // Get the current values from the TimePicker
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                hours = timePicker.hour
                minutes = timePicker.minute
            } else {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                hours = timePicker.currentHour
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                minutes = timePicker.currentMinute
            }

            // Generate value to save
            val minutesAfterMidnight = hours * 60 + minutes

            // Save the value
            preference.apply {
                // This allows the client to ignore the user value.
                if (callChangeListener(minutesAfterMidnight)) {
                    // Save the value
                    time = minutesAfterMidnight
                }
            }
            preference.summary = "$hours:${if (minutes < 10) "0$minutes" else "$minutes"}"
        }
    }

    override fun getPreference(): TimePickerPreference {
        return super.getPreference() as? TimePickerPreference
            ?: error("Preference is not a TimePreference")
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(key: String?) = TimePickerPreferenceDialog().apply {
            arguments = Bundle(1).apply {
                putString(ARG_KEY, key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much